# How to draw some new lines without re-drawing all the existing lines with onDraw() in Android?

Tags: android, ondraw

I want to make a drawing panel with android. What I am doint right now is that I have to re-draw every existing lines and the new line, so it makes my app working slowly when there're too many lines on canvas. Is there any possible ways that I can actually add some new points to the canvas without the other points disappearing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
invalidate(r);
```

where

```
Rect r; // part of the screen
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but I found that I have to make the whole screen dirty all the time. Is there any other possible ways of doing this?